# What does "Vietnam veterans" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The valor of **the Vietnam veterans** deserves the highest commendation.

Does it mean *soldiers who fought in Vietnam* or *Vietnamese soldiers*?

Comment: Fought there, against Vietnam. It's a very US-centric term.

Comment: They are _soldiers who fought in Vietnam_. Vietnamese (ex-)soldiers would be _Vietnamese veterans_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to soldiers who fought in what is known in the US as The Vietnam War, against the North Vietnamese regime when that country was divided north/south.

The name of the country where the conflict took place is used adjectivally:

***Vietnam* veterans**

In England you will find, for example, "*Falklands* Veterans".

Comment: And in the Sherlock Holmes stories, Watson is an Afghan Veteran.  You also have WWII Veterans and any other war.  Following the construction:  'Conflict name' veteran.  (being someone who fought and survived the fighting in the conflict)  Seams that the 'war' is dropped in every instance I can think of out side of World War 1 and 2.